# Redirection from PushNotification to particular Page when App is closed not working in iOS

Tags: apple-push-notifications

When the app is in closed state & the notification comes the app get launched but it do not redirect to the page we redirect it.

Comment: In my app i want to redirect my app to particular mail whose id is been passed to didReceiveLocalNotification in its userinfo but unable to achieve this functionality. I am able to handle Active & Inactive states of app on receiving notification for redirection, but when the app is completely closed could not perform the functionality of redirection.

Answer (score 0):

i used same one on my app. be sure you are handling navigation controller correctly and navigate it in your main page. For that you can use custom loading view ect. as main page.